# ASP .NET GridView not displaying rows

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I am working on a company web app.

My ASP .NET GridView was working fine but I do not know what changes I made that made it to stop displaying rows. It only displays one row or no rows at all.

This is my code:

```
private void BindAnnualLeaveGrid() 
{
    try {
        string s = (string)Session["Status"];
        if (s == null)
            s = "Approved";
        Employee emp = (Employee)Session["Employee"];
        DataTable table = DataAccess.GetLeave("Annual", s, emp.Id);
        this.gvUserAnnualLeave.DataSource = table;
        this.gvUserAnnualLeave.DataBind();
        Debug.WriteLine("this.gvUserAnnualLeave.Rows.Count=" + this.gvUserAnnualLeave.Rows.Count);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

The line  Debug.WriteLine("this.gvUserAnnualLeave.Rows.Count=" + this.gvUserAnnualLeave.Rows.Count); prints 4 rows, SO THERE ARE ROWS IN THE DATATABLE.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the ASPX code:

```
 <asp:Table ID="Table5" runat="server" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Annual Leave Summary" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#022439"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvUserAnnualLeave" runat="server" CssClass="GridView"
                            ShowFooter="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvUserAnnualLeave_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ItemID"
                            AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvUserAnnualLeave_PageIndexChanging"
                            PageSize="15">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="ItemID" SortExpression="ItemID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Absence" HeaderText="Absence" SortExpression="Absence" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" dataformatstring="{0:dd-M-yyyy}" HeaderText="StartDate" SortExpression="StartDate" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" dataformatstring="{0:dd-M-yyyy}" HeaderText="EndDate" SortExpression="EndDate" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeId" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Days" HeaderText="Days" SortExpression="Days" />
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#022439" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                No Data To Display!
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
```

Comment: _"SO THERE ARE ROWS IN THE DATATABLE."_ Not only that but also your GridView contains those rows since you use `gvUserAnnualLeave.Rows.Count` instead of `table.Rows.Count`. So it must be a display or css issue.

Comment: Try inspecting the outputed page in your browser using development tool (F12 in Firefox, Chrome and IE). to see if the outputed HTML contains your rows.

Comment: When I view source, there is only one row being returned.